# Graph in c,and its implementation

Tags: c

Node definition of a graph in c:

```
struct AdjListNode
{
int dest;
struct AdjListNode* next;
};
```

What will the list definition?

Comment: @GillBates: More important: What is the question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
struct AdjList
{
struct AdjListNode *head;
};


struct Graph
{
int V;
struct AdjList* array;
};
```

visit here:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/